# How can i make spring batch read from uploaded file via rest controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-batch

```
    @Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Student> reader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Student>()
            .name("studentItemReader")
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("Student.csv"))
            .delimited()
            .names("id", "name")
            .lineMapper(lineMapper())
            .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Student>() {{
                setTargetType(Student.class);
            }}).build();
}
```

**I can only read static file,I would like to read from rest controller**

Comment: What do you mean by "read from rest controller"? Do you mean read from rest endpoint?

Comment: I would like to upload CSV file first from rest controller (Multipart file) and read from it. Is it possible?

Comment: All file readers in Spring Batch work against the `Resource` abstraction from Spring Framework. So if you use a `UrlResource` pointing to the file, it should work. However, what if you read the file and then upload it instead of uploading the file then read from it?

Comment: okay, I will try reading the file and uploading it. thank you for your help